# Client is using WCF that wants to communicate with this JDE (JD Edward) Web service

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, jdeveloper, jdedwards

I have one requirement where our client is having a portal to create tickets....
their portal will send the data created by calling a WCF service to store into JDE system.
They prefer to ahve WCF web service. Using WCF they will send request in jde system, after that JDE system should compute the completion date and send back to them with the same request.
In order to achieve this we need jde provider bssv as wcf service.

Can anyone help how to create this? step by step giude would be helpful.

Thanks...

Regards,
Parag

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this documentation already? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jde-bssv-database-business-service-131800.pdf

EDIT 2014-10-16
Here is a step by step guide that will help you with that you want.
http://www.jdelist.com/vb4/attachment.php?attachmentid=5900&d=1236332152

In short.

1. Create a WCF project
2. Add a reference to MS WSE
3. Create a WebReference with the url to the WDSL of JDE BSSV
4. Map the BSSV classes to your WCF functions.

Comment: Hi..This document we know...it just saying how to create JDE Web service (BSSV)....we would like to create the WCF service using that JDE BSSV...something like one more wrapper on the top of BSSV...